# Set focus to first empty input or textarea with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the focus to the first blank `input` or `textarea` field on a page. This works with `input`s, but not with `textarea`s.

```
$(':input:text[value=""]').first().focus()
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can try looking with something like

```
$("textarea:empty,input:text[value='']").first().focus();
```

Text areas don't have a value at all as they are called with

```
<textarea>Content</textarea>
```

working example
http://www.bootply.com/ikSuqoPMqs

Comment: It should work well for you now exactly how you want it to.

Comment: Great to hear that it worked for you. A nice simple solution. :) Please accept the answer and upvote. :)

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to find all `input` and `textarea` on the page in the correct order. You can query using their tag names `$('input, textarea')`, but to maintain the correct order use a class on all of them (`.inputClass` in the example). Then filter the non empty ones, and `.focus()` the 1st:

```js
//** search for the input class and filter the elements found **/

var emptyAreas = $('.inputClass').filter(function(index, element) {
  return $.trim($(element).val()) === ''; // element .val() is '' after trimming white spaces = true
});

emptyAreas.first().focus(); // get the 1st element and focus it
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  
  <li><input class="inputClass" value="text"></li>

  <li><textarea class="inputClass"></textarea></li>

  <li><input class="inputClass" value="  "></li>

  <li><textarea class="inputClass">text</textarea></li>

  <li><textarea class="inputClass">   </textarea></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

```js
$(':text, textarea').on('blur', function(e) {
  var emptyField = $(':text, textarea').filter(function(index, element) {
    return element.value == '';
  });
  if (emptyField.length > 0) {
    emptyField.first().focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>


<form>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    Comment:<br>
    <textarea name="comment" form="usrform"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good point on the .inputClass. @Ori Drori

I've improved your answer a bit. Excluding hidden fields and adding the .inputClass dynamically.

```
// adding .inputClass to inputs to maintain the order in the filter below
$('input, textarea').addClass('inputClass');
const emptyAreas = $('.inputClass').filter(function (index, element) {
    const hidden = $(element).is('hidden') || $(element).attr('type') === 'hidden'; // excluding hidden elements
    return !hidden && $.trim($(element).val()) === ''; // element .val() is '' after trimming white spaces
});

emptyAreas.first().focus(); // get the 1st element and focus it
```